# Vue router <router-link></router-link> is not working with bootstrap data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I try to create my own component to combine vue router `<router-link></router-link>` with bootstrap `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`.

So the problem happens when trying to click on link, but it's not clickable. If I remove `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` from `router-link` everything is fine.

```
<template>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link
            class="nav-link py-2 px-md-2"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
            :to="{ name: router }"
            :class="{active: $router.name === router, styles}"
        >
            <slot />
        </router-link>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'NavItem',
    props: {
        router: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        styles: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with creating a `collpase_navbar` method, that we could call to close navbar when needed.

```
collapse_navbar() {
        const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar-collapse.show');
        if (navbar) {
            new bootstrap.Collapse(navbar, {
                toggle: false,
            }).hide();
        }
    },
```